# Sending metrics from telegraf to prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, telegraf

I'm running `prometheus` and `telegraf` on the same host.

I'm using a few inputs plugins:

- inputs.cpu
- inputs.ntpq

I've configured to the `prometheus_client` output plugin to send data to prometheus

Here's my config:

```
    [[outputs.prometheus_client]]
      ## Address to listen on.
      listen = ":9126"

      ## Use HTTP Basic Authentication.
      # basic_username = "Foo"
      # basic_password = "Bar"

      ## If set, the IP Ranges which are allowed to access metrics.
      ##   ex: ip_range = ["192.168.0.0/24", "192.168.1.0/30"]
      # ip_range = []

      ## Path to publish the metrics on.
      path = "/metrics"

      ## Expiration interval for each metric. 0 == no expiration
      #expiration_interval = "0s"

      ## Collectors to enable, valid entries are "gocollector" and "process".
      ## If unset, both are enabled.
      # collectors_exclude = ["gocollector", "process"]

      ## Send string metrics as Prometheus labels.
      ## Unless set to false all string metrics will be sent as labels.
      # string_as_label = true

      ## If set, enable TLS with the given certificate.
      # tls_cert = "/etc/ssl/telegraf.crt"
      # tls_key = "/etc/ssl/telegraf.key"

      ## Export metric collection time.
      #export_timestamp = true

Here's my prometheus config

# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

#  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
#    scrape_interval: 5s
#    static_configs:
#      - targets: ['localhost:9100']

  - job_name: 'telegraf'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9126']
```

If i'm going to `http://localhost:9090/metrics` i don't see any metrics which are coming from telegraf.

I've captured some logs from telegraf as well

`/opt telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --input-filter filestat --test
➜  /opt tail -F  /var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log
2019-02-11T17:34:20Z D! [outputs.prometheus_client] wrote batch of 28 metrics in 1.234869ms
2019-02-11T17:34:20Z D! [outputs.prometheus_client] buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics.
2019-02-11T17:34:30Z D! [outputs.file] wrote batch of 28 metrics in 384.672µs
2019-02-11T17:34:30Z D! [outputs.file] buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics.
2019-02-11T17:34:30Z D! [outputs.prometheus_client] wrote batch of 30 metrics in 1.250605ms
2019-02-11T17:34:30Z D! [outputs.prometheus_client] buffer fullness: 9 / 10000 metrics.`

I don't see an issue in the logs.

Comment: did you fix it ? facing the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/metrics` endpoint of your Prometheus server exports metrics about the server itself, not metrics that it scraped from targets like the telgraf exporter.

Go to `http://localhost:9090/targets`, you should see a list of targets that your Prometheus server is scraping. If configured correctly, the telegraf exporter should be one of them.

To query Prometheus for telegraf exporter generated metrics, navigate your browser to `http://localhost:9090/graph` and enter e.g. `cpu_time_user` in the query field. If the CPU plugin is enabled it should have that and more metrics.

Comment: what should the url for the telegraf metrics endpoint be? going by OP config `http://localhost:9126/metrics` ?

Comment: Yes, telegraf metrics endpoint will be http://localhost:9126/metrics

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following Prometheus config file in order to scrape metrics exported by `prometheus_client` at Telegraf:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: telegraf
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - "localhost:9126"
```

Path to this file must be passed to `--config.file` command-line flag when starting Prometheus.

See more details about Prometheus config in [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

P.S. There is an alternative solution to push metrics collected by Telegraf  directly to Prometheus-like system such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) instead of InfluxDB - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-send-data-from-influxdb-compatible-agents-such-as-telegraf). Later these metrics can be queried with PromQL-compatible query language - [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).