# How can I add multiple panels to Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, telegraf

I want to see the cpu or features of more than one computer on Grafana, what can I do, the program I use is prometheus

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat new to Grafana, but I believe I know the answer to this. I believe that Prometheus scrapes the data, and you probably have some exporter that Prometheus is scraping from (windows-exporter, node exporter, a database, etc.). What you want to do is edit the `prometheus.yml` file and add another job name with the newly added exporter as a target. [Here is a guide for node exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/#configuring-your-prometheus-instances), and I think that other exporters should have a very similar setup. Hope this helps!

Comment: I did what you said, but when I enter the IP of my second server in the directory, it does not give the information of that IP, grafana crashes and gives a bad gateway warning to the values ​​I entered.

Comment: Could you send your `prometheus.yml` file, the exact error message, and then the software you are running on your machines (specifically what you are using to export data to Prometheus, such as windows-exporter, node-exporter, or a database)? That information should make troubleshooting this issue a lot easier.

Comment: I am using the program called telegraf and I cannot see the values ​​of the other server in grafana with the data I entered, I do not know what I assign to the prometheus value, or what I do will be solved.

Comment: [This Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636124/sending-metrics-from-telegraf-to-prometheus)  contain details that sound similar to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
hostname: localhost
volumes:
 - ./config/telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
 - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
 - /sys:/rootfs/sys:ro
 - /proc:/rootfs/proc:ro
 - /etc:/rootfs/etc:ro
networks:
 - back-tier
```

how can i open docker code to outside network