# Send Prometheus query from telegraf to VictoriaMetrics DB

Tags: database, prometheus, telegraf, victoriametrics, telegraf-inputs-plugin

Did anyone know if it is possible to collect metric directly by sending a prometheus query in telegraf to VictoriaMetrics ?

I have tried this but it is not working :/

```
[inputs]
[[inputs.prometheus]]
urls = ["http://my_db_address:8428"]
query = "ifHCOutOctets_counter{target="device"}"
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Prometheus query is valid data in system.if issue persists victoria metrics logs connection problem.Adusjust query with single quotes.Not use double quotes.

Comment: The one quote didn't change anything. in telegraf logs i am getting this error : configuration specified the fields ["query"], but they weren't use

Comment: AFAIK It looks like [[inputs.prometheus]] is using only for polling metrics and not to query them from telegraf, see https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ainfluxdata%2Ftelegraf%20inputs.prometheus&type=code , see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636124/sending-metrics-from-telegraf-to-prometheus

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config for Telegraf:

```
[[inputs.prometheus]]
urls = ["http://my_db_address:8428/federate?match[]=ifHCOutOctets_counter{target='device'}"]
```

It uses [/federate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#federation) endpoint for obtaining the last values for metrics matching the given [filters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#filtering). The `/federate` endpoint returns metrics in the same format as usual Prometheus exporters do at `/metrics` page.